# Integrate example of Atmosphere with spring

Tags: spring, websocket, atmosphere

I'm starting with Atmosphere, so I have some doubts and difficulties.

How could I integrate this example http://blog.javaforge.net/post/32659151672/atmosphere-per-session-broadcaster with Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You try this example:

https://github.com/keaplogik/springMVC-atmosphere-comet-websockets

But this is not good idea, I think.

Atmosphere with spring is too heavy, if you are developing a little app, native websocket or asyncServlet is better then Atmosphere.

Comment: Atmosphere provides fallback to Comet automatically. Comet is a bit tricky to implement manually because you need to add some padding due to issues with Firefox.